# Flight Ticket to around the world

Tags: around-the-world

Where I found the ticket to flight around the world.

I'm living in Sydney and I'm plan a trip of 3/4 months in Asia and Middle East. I'm not sure if use a flight is the best way to do this travel. Probably I'll enjoy more if I use more buses and trains.

Probably this is my route ( not in order )

- Vietnam
- India
- Jordan
- Egypt
- Greece
- Turkey
- Nepal
- Camboja
- Russia
- China
- Kazakhastan
- Bangladesh
- Hong Kong
- Taiwan

I'm a photographer.

Someone have a recommendations.

Comment: You may change the question to something more overall like World Fare Tickets overall. So this still can exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds exiciting Coehlo!

Anyway regarding you questions you probably should check out the big Alliances like StarAlliance, OneWorld and SkyTeam.

Take a look here:

1. **Star Alliance - Round the World:** You would have to make a stop somewhere in the US to get really AROUND the world. (http://www.staralliance.com/en/fares/round-the-world-fare)
2. **SkyTeam - Go Round the World:** http://www.skyteam.com/your-trip/Travel-Passes/Go-Global/
3. **OneWorld - Round-the-world fares:** http://www.oneworld.com/flights/round-the-world-fares
4. And maybe the **Google ITA Search Matrix**: http://matrix.itasoftware.com/ which let you check several airlines, times, airports and whatsoever.

**Example:** I only know the Star Alliance System and you would have to really travel around the world (so making a flight within e.g. the US too). I just created an example for you using the Star Alliance World Ticket App (see ref: `819f-7a3b-18a8-5ee9`) which will lead you to most of the countries you mentioned. The fare thereby e.g. would be around 7.500 AUD.